# Convert from Dict to JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I want to construct a dict in Python which with json.dumps(arg) will convert to the following JSON structure:

```
"{\"type\":\"id\",
\"entries:\":
[[\"a\",91],
[\"b\",65],
[\"c\",26],
[\"d\",25]]}"
```

This is what I have so far:

```
json_dict = {'type': str("id"),
            'entries': [['a': "91"], #Error line
                        ['b': "65"],
                        ['c': "26"],
                        ['d': "25"]]}
```

I am getting "invalid syntax" error on the line which is marked with #Error line. How can I represent this hierarchical structure in a dict and still be able to convert it to the desired JSON structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python lists use commas, not colons:

```
json_dict = {'type': str("id"),
            'entries': [['a', "91"],  # note the comma after 'a', not a colon
                        ['b', "65"],
                        ['c', "26"],
                        ['d', "25"]]}
```

With commas, this is now valid Python syntax, producing a data structure that can be serialised to JSON:

```
>>> json_dict = {'type': str("id"),
...             'entries': [['a', "91"],
...                         ['b', "65"],
...                         ['c', "26"],
...                         ['d', "25"]]}
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps(json_dict)
'{"type": "id", "entries": [["a", "91"], ["b", "65"], ["c", "26"], ["d", "25"]]}'
```

Comment: Oh!!! The syntaxes are so similar I got it mixed up. This fixed it straight away. Thanks!